# WSUS refuse to install

Tags: wsus, sql-server-2012, sccm-2012

Dears..
I hope you are doing well..

I am facing issue with WSUS. Actually, It was working fine and works with SCCM until an issue appears. So,  I decided to reinstall WSUS, but I faced another problem.. when I specify DB instance and content path  and give the bellow error:

[image]

One solution I found is to remove sites from IIS in the same server and I deleted, but the issue not resolved. IS there any issues regarding deleting the sites from IIS??

the following screen shot for IIS after reinstalling

[image]

Could you please help me with this issue

Answer (score -1):

It's an issue caused by SP3 being installed before .NET Framework 3.0 as yet there's no automatic fix but if you only have the issue on a few machines you can fix it by downloading .net framework 3.5 installing that manually then letting 3.0 install via AU.

Comment: for test purpose, I set up full WSUS with SCCM enviroment in VM. I delted the sites that created by WSUS in IIS. The up error appears.

Comment: Do you have any idea to recreate the sites in IIS ?